# Filtering queries from data frame on date part using sqldf

Tags: r

I am trying to extract and join 2 data frames based on some date parts but its not working. The data frames are as follows :-

```
startdf

startperiod
2015-10-01
2016-10-01
2017-10-01
2018-10-01


enddf

endperiod
2016-03-31
2017-03-31
2018-03-31
```

Both `startperiod` and `endperiod` are of 'Date' data type

This is final output I desire :-

```
startperiod, endperiod
2015-10-01  2016-03-31
2016-10-01  2017-03-31
2017-10-01  2018-03-31
2018-10-01  Null
```

The equivalent SQL would be something like this :-

```
Select startperiod, endperiod
From startdf a lef join enddf b
On year(b.endperiod) = (year(a.startperiod) + 1)
```

is there a way to do in R? I believe I need to use library `sqldf` and `RH2` but I couldn't get it going no matter what I did.

Simplistically, this should work but doesn't!

```
sqldf("Select * from startperioddf a where year(startperiod) = 2016")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sqldf` package in R uses the `SQLite` database engine by default. Hence, you cannot use the `year` function in your query to extract the year part from the date. The following query will do the job:

`sqldf("Select * from startdf where strftime('%Y', startperiod) = '2016'")`

It uses SQLite's `strftime` function to compare specific date parts. The `year` function is defined under `MySQL` so you may have to install the `RMySQL` package and then use the `drv = 'MySQL'` argument to specify the database engine that you want `sqldf` to use.

Comment: Siddharth <- Will try that. What about joining those 2 data frames as shown in my original query where endperiod year = startperod year + 1. How would you do that?

Comment: It didn't return any rows <- sqldf("Select * from startperioddf where strftime(startperiod, '%Y') = '2016'") <-
[1] startperiod newdate    
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Comment: Tried both ways with '%Y' before and after the variable name - same result as above.

Answer (score 1):

**1) RH2** Assuming

- the data shown in reproducible form in the Note below.  In particular, note that `startdate` and `enddate` are assumed to be of `Date` class.
- typos in the question are fixed
- use of h2 database backend instead of the default sqlite

then your code works:

```
library(sqldf)
library(RH2)

sql <- "Select startperiod, endperiod
  From startdf a left join enddf b
  On year(b.endperiod) = (year(a.startperiod) + 1)"
sqldf(sql)
```

giving:

```
  startperiod  endperiod
1  2015-10-01 2016-03-31
2  2016-10-01 2017-03-31
3  2017-10-01 2018-03-31
4  2018-10-01       <NA>
```

Also

```
sqldf("Select * from startdf a where year(startperiod) = 2016")
```

giving:

```
  startperiod
1  2016-10-01
```

Be sure to read the material on the sqldf github site: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf

**2) sqlite** If you want to use the default sqlite backend then be sure that RH2 is NOT loaded (otherwise, it will assume you want to use it) and note that Date class variables will be uploaded to sqlite as integers representing the number of days since the unix epoch (since there is no Date class type in sqlite) so we need to convert days since the epoch to years (which can be done using `strftime` as shown).

```
sql2 <- "Select startperiod, endperiod
  From startdf a left join enddf b
  On strftime('%Y', b.endperiod * 3600 * 24, 'unixepoch') + 0 = 
     strftime('%Y', a.startperiod * 3600 * 24, 'unixepoch') + 1"
sqldf(sql2)

sqldf("Select * from startdf a 
  where strftime('%Y', a.startperiod * 3600 * 24, 'unixepoch') = '2016'")
```

### Note

```
Lines1 <- "
startperiod
2015-10-01
2016-10-01
2017-10-01
2018-10-01"

Lines2 <- "
endperiod
2016-03-31
2017-03-31
2018-03-31"

startdf <- read.table(text = Lines1, header = TRUE, colClasses = "Date")
enddf <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE, colClasses = "Date")
```

Comment: G.Grothendieck <- SQLite version worked. Thanks for that. The other one didn't. There was error - "Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection. Error in !dbPreExists : invalid argument type". Any idea how can I fix this? I would prefer to use the RH2 version. Also, how do you get to insert the newline character in the original question, I tried but couldn't. Can you please point me to some place where I can get the editing right? <- Deepak

Comment: Start up a new instance of R and ensure that R and all packages are up to date and that you have Java installed.  Then enter the code in the Note and then enter the code in the body of answer in point (1) and you will get the output that I pasted into the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try that now and report back!

Comment: Just tried on a new instance of R Studio and comes up with the same error. Errors are like so. "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details: call: fun(libname, pkgname) error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry". <- Is this to do with our instalation constraints on our work laptops? <- Deepak

Comment: I can't reproduce that. I tried it under R using Windows, under RStudio using Windows and under R using Linux and it gave the answer shown in my answer all 3 times. Are you sure you followed the instructions in my prior comment exactly?

Comment: Also, there may be something wrong with your Java installation.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong. You have done more that what I expected. It appears that there is something not quite right with our Java installation. I have requested our IT dept to check if they can install the 64 bit version to coincide with the R and RStudio versions. Hopefully, that should fix it. Will keep you posed.